# How to use jsoncpp from fetchcontent

Tags: c++, cmake, jsoncpp

I'm making one program that is basically a stresstest for a couple of different machines, and I have to write the testresults to a jsonformat.

Because I don't want to manually install jsoncpp on every machine I decided to use Fetchcontent in the CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Programma)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        jsoncpp
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
        GIT_TAG        master
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(jsoncpp)
if (NOT jsoncpp_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(jsoncpp)
    add_subdirectory(${jsoncpp_SOURCE_DIR} ${jsoncpp_BINARY_DIR})
    message(${jsoncpp_SOURCE_DIR})
    message(${jsoncpp_BINARY_DIR})
endif ()

#FetchContent_MakeAvailable(jsoncpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Programma main.cpp)
add_library(TestSubjects.cpp TransformTests.cpp FoldTests.cpp
        TestResults.h SortTests.cpp FindTests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Programma Tests jsoncpp)
```

but I tried a couple of header includes like `<json.h>` `<jsoncpp/json.h>` `json/json.h>` but none of them work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your library (or executable) uses headers from jsoncpp library, then it should **link** to that library. I don't see that linkage (which is performed with `target_link_libraries`) in your code.

Comment: Ah yeah true, I tried that, but to no avail

Comment: Dependent on what **kind** - STATIC, SHARED or OBJECT, - of jsoncpp library you want to use, the name of the **target** is `jsoncpp_static`, `jsoncpp_lib` and `jsoncpp_object` correspondingly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev actually it is an answer. Then correct include directive should be `#include <json/json.h>`

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried it with `target_link_libraries(Programma Tests jsoncpp_lib)` But it still doesn't find it. The compiler said it did make the target thought

Comment: Please, add into the question post the **exact error message** you got. That error message should include paths to files involved into it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It's pretty long so I made a pastebin: https://pastebin.pl/view/ffc8b5ec ... basically the error says: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'Json'
    Json::Value array(Json::arrayValue);`

Comment: WAIT, I GOT IT. It was jsoncpp_lib and <json/json.h> and restarting Clion

Comment: If you resolved the issue, please create an answer post describing (and showing code) what you changed to fix the issue so other viewers may learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While being built, the project `jsoncpp` doesn't provide `jsoncpp` **target**. Instead, it provides separate targets for different kind of library:

- `jsoncpp_static` for STATIC library,
- `jsoncpp_lib` for SHARED library,
- `jsoncpp_object` for OBJECT library.

By default, all 3 library kinds are built, so you may choose **any** of them for link with:

```
target_link_libraries(Programma jsoncpp_lib)
```

Also, the correct include directive is

```
#include <json/json.h>
```