# Controlling the build order when using FetchContent with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I've done this example on Ubuntu 22.04.3, where I have:

```
$ cmake --version | head -1
cmake version 3.22.1
```

So, let's say I have these two files in `/tmp/cmake_mytest`:

**`CMakeLists.txt`**:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
include(FetchContent)    #Note this

FetchContent_Declare(
  jsoncpp
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp
  GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
  GIT_TAG        69098a1 # Jun 27, 2023, latest in Jan 2024
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(jsoncpp)
add_library(jsoncpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(jsoncpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${jsoncpp_BINARY_DIR}/src/lib_json/libjsoncpp.a)

project(mytest C CXX ASM)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources
  main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${jsoncpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

**`main.cpp`**:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

SO, I have:

```
$ tree /tmp/cmake_mytest/
/tmp/cmake_mytest/
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

Note that at this point, `main.cpp` is just an "empty shell"/"skeleton", and needs no libraries to link.

So, then I try to run `cmake`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/cmake_mytest/build && cd /tmp/cmake_mytest/build

$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-- Populating jsoncpp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild
[ 11%] Creating directories for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 22%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'jsoncpp-populate'
Cloning into 'jsoncpp-src'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8551, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (133/133), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (83/83), done.        
remote: Total 8551 (delta 70), reused 79 (delta 46), pack-reused 8418        
Receiving objects: 100% (8551/8551), 2.90 MiB | 8.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5408/5408), done.
HEAD is now at 69098a1 Avoid using cmake glob vars if we are a subproject (#1459)
[ 33%] Performing update step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 44%] No patch step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 55%] No configure step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 66%] No build step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 77%] No install step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 88%] No test step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[100%] Completed 'jsoncpp-populate'
[100%] Built target jsoncpp-populate
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- JsonCpp Version: 1.9.5
-- Looking for C++ include clocale
-- Looking for C++ include clocale - found
-- Looking for localeconv
-- Looking for localeconv - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h - found
-- Check size of lconv
-- Check size of lconv - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_DECIMAL_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_DECIMAL_POINT - Success
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.12") found components: Interpreter 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build
```

..., and then `make`

```
$ make
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable mytest
[ 10%] Built target mytest
[ 15%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 31%] Linking CXX shared library libjsoncpp.so
[ 31%] Built target jsoncpp_lib
[ 36%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Linking CXX static library libjsoncpp.a
[ 52%] Built target jsoncpp_static
[ 57%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 68%] Built target jsoncpp_object
[ 73%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable jsontestrunner_exe
[ 78%] Built target jsontestrunner_exe
[ 84%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/jsontest.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/fuzz.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable jsoncpp_test
Testing ValueTest/checkNormalizeFloatingPointStr: OK
...
Testing VersionTest/VersionNumbersMatch: OK
All 119 tests passed
[100%] Built target jsoncpp_test
```

Note that here, `main.cpp` gets built - compiled and linked - **first**; however, since it is just an empty skeleton, its build completes successfully; and only afterwards, does the FetchContent'd `jsoncpp` library build, with the following files:

```
$ find . -name '*.a' -o -name '*.so'
./_deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/libjsoncpp.so
./_deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/libjsoncpp.a
```

So, if at this point, I change `main.cpp` to:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <json/json.h> // jsoncpp

Json::Value myjson;

int main(void) {
  myjson["test"] = "mytest";

  Json::StyledWriter styled; // or Json::FastWriter fast;
  std::string sStyled = styled.write(myjson);
  std::cout << "sStyled " << sStyled << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

... and I add the following lines to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
# ...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${jsoncpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC  # added
  ${jsoncpp_BINARY_DIR}                         # added
)                                               # added
                                                # added
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC    # added
  jsoncpp                                       # added
)                                               # added
```

... then if I run `make` again, `cmake` runs to update, but otherwise the build completes:

```
$ make
-- Populating jsoncpp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
[ 11%] Performing update step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 22%] No patch step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 33%] No configure step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 44%] No build step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 55%] No install step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 66%] No test step for 'jsoncpp-populate'
[ 77%] Completed 'jsoncpp-populate'
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
[100%] Built target jsoncpp-populate
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/cmake_mytest/build/_deps/jsoncpp-subbuild'
-- JsonCpp Version: 1.9.5
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mytest
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable mytest
[ 10%] Built target mytest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsoncpp_lib
[ 31%] Built target jsoncpp_lib
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsoncpp_static
[ 52%] Built target jsoncpp_static
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsoncpp_object
[ 68%] Built target jsoncpp_object
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsontestrunner_exe
[ 78%] Built target jsontestrunner_exe
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsoncpp_test
[100%] Built target jsoncpp_test
```

Note that the build succeeded, because the `jsoncpp` libraries got built previously.

HOWEVER - now if I *delete* the contents of the `build/` folder, and try to repeat the build again:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/cmake_mytest/build

$ rm -rf *
$ ls
$ 

$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build

$ make
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '_deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/libjsoncpp.a', needed by 'mytest'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:218: CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

... now the build *fails* - because CMake has, as we've seen earlier, set up thes project to build main.cpp first, *before* the dependent libraries from FetchContent have been built - and so even if the compile step succeeds, the linking step fails (since there are no built library files to link to!)

So, how can I control the build order, so that the libraries obtained via FetchContent in cmake are built *first*, *before* my actual program files are compiled and built?

Comment: In `target_link_libraries` it is better to specify not a library *name* ("jsoncpp" in your case), but the library **target** created in the subproject. That way, CMake not only automatically deduces path to the library file, but also adjusts needed build dependencies. Also, CMake automatically adds include directories shipped with that target, so call `target_include_directories` won't be needed. As you could find from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63736888/3440745) on the duplicate question, the possible targets to link with are `jsoncpp_static`, `jsoncpp_lib` and `jsoncpp_object`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the answer for controlling the build order in CMake is, as usual, `add_dependencies`.

First of all, note that I did not really need these lines in CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
add_library(jsoncpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(jsoncpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${jsoncpp_BINARY_DIR}/src/lib_json/libjsoncpp.a)
```

If those are removed, the error I got in OP is instead:

```
...
-- JsonCpp Version: 1.9.5
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mytest
[  5%] Linking CXX executable mytest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljsoncpp: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/build.make:97: mytest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:218: CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Anyways - since I want to link statically, the trick is to actually see what the CMake target for the static library is called in `jsoncpp` - and that was dumped as part of this output of `make` in OP:

```
...
[ 31%] Linking CXX shared library libjsoncpp.so
[ 31%] Built target jsoncpp_lib
[ 36%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Linking CXX static library libjsoncpp.a
[ 52%] Built target jsoncpp_static
[ 57%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
...
```

So, the CMake target for the static library is called `jsoncpp_static`. So *this* is what we should use in `add_dependencies` to enforce the build order - and what we should use in `target_link_libraries` as well (and then we do not even need to use `target_link_directories`).

So finally, this is the corrected `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
include(FetchContent)    #Note this

FetchContent_Declare(
  jsoncpp
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp
  GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
  GIT_TAG        69098a1 # Jun 27, 2023, latest in Jan 2024
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(jsoncpp)

project(mytest C CXX ASM)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources
  main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${jsoncpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC      # added
  jsoncpp_static                                  # added
)                                                 # added
                                                  # added
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp_static)  # added
```

... and this is how the build looks from scratch:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/cmake_mytest/build
$ rm -rf *
$ ls
$

$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-- Populating jsoncpp
-- Configuring done
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake_mytest/build

$ make
[  5%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 21%] Linking CXX static library libjsoncpp.a
[ 21%] Built target jsoncpp_static
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 31%] Linking CXX executable mytest
[ 31%] Built target mytest
[ 36%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Linking CXX shared library libjsoncpp.so
[ 52%] Built target jsoncpp_lib
[ 57%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_value.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_object.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 68%] Built target jsoncpp_object
[ 73%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable jsontestrunner_exe
[ 78%] Built target jsontestrunner_exe
[ 84%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/jsontest.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/fuzz.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object _deps/jsoncpp-build/src/test_lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable jsoncpp_test
Testing ValueTest/checkNormalizeFloatingPointStr: OK
...
Testing VersionTest/VersionNumbersMatch: OK
All 119 tests passed
[100%] Built target jsoncpp_test
```

So, first jsoncpp_static (libjsoncpp.a) gets built, then my executable gets build and links successfully to the static library, exactly as desired (and then all remaining targets from jsoncpp library get built, but that does not really matter to me here) - in any case, the build completes successfully from scratch, which is what I wanted.